# Should a directive talk to a controller in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have been watching the videos by John Linquist and in one video he gives this as an example:

```
var app = angular.module('twitterApp', [])

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
   $scope.loadMoreTweets = function () {
      alert("Loading tweets!");
   }
}

app.directive("enter", function() {
   return function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
         scope.LoadMoreTweets();
      })
   }
}
```

One thing I am wondering about is should the directive in this example talk back to the controller or would it be a better programming practice to create a service and then have the directive talk to a service? I guess I am still not sure if it is common practices for directives to talk to controllers in this way.

[U tube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJmZaxuxlRc&list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7&index=14)

Comment: That's pretty much what services are meant for, I guess. Just my two cents...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How I would have done it

```
<span enter="loadMoreTweets()">Something</span>
```

JS

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.loadMoreTweets = function () {
      console.log("Loading tweets!");
   }  
})



app.directive("enter", function() {
   return {
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
          scope.$apply(attrs.enter)
       })
     }
   }
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/seVRv7lgkXQzvV74t85Q?p=preview)

Another way to achieve the same

```
app.directive("enter", function() {
   return {
    scope: {
      callback: '&enter'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
          scope.$apply('callback()')
       })
     }
   }
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DrruUYZPMiKsX5ROilh3)

Comment: I think your suggestion is pretty much the same as John came up with later in the video. But would you consider anything other than putting the loadMoreTweets into a service rather than the controller?

Comment: IMHO: I don't think service is the way to go here, you need to the directive need to be considered only about mouseenter, what need to be done in mouse enter is a separate concern

Comment: that said the controller could delegate the actual tweets loading to  service layer

Comment: with your second suggestion is that something similar to a custom implementation of ngClick but for mouse enter and for calling a function. I am wondering if there are other ways to implement mouse enter. Time for me to check out google.

Comment: I think your Plunkers have some problem. I tried both but could not get them to work.

Comment: @Gemma yes, look like some problem with save, I'm looking into it

Answer (score 4):

**Is it common practice?**

Yes that is common practice, directives frequently need to access the $scope for variables, and to call methods (like `LoadMoreTweets`).

Even in the [official docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) they have examples like..

```
scope.$watch(...)
```

...fom inside a directive (where the controller might be making changes to the watched variable).

It is entirely appropriate for a directive to communicate with a controller in this way.

You can even inject a controller itself (not just the scope) into the `link` method of a directive. Looks at the "Linking function" section of http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

*"The controller is shared among all the directives, which allows the directives to use the controllers as a communication channel."*

**But *could* I use a service?**

Sure you could. The question is why? If you are working with a single page (that displays tweets for example) and the controller already has a `$scope.tweets` variable and `$scope.loadMoreTweets` method, you are overcomplicating things if you try to stick a service in there where it's not needed.

On the other hand services are perfect for *application wide* data, like user profile. If your directive needed to access the currently logged in user, then it makes a lot of sense to do that via service.

From the docs:

*Angular services are singletons that carry out specific tasks common to web apps, such as the $http service that provides low level access to the browser's XMLHttpRequest object.*

**If you have a application-wide task that is best suited for a singleton, by all means use a service. If you just need to access/modify the $scope from a directive, just talk directly to the controller, or trigger an event that the controller can respond to.**

Comment: But could a service be used for this? It looks confusing for me to have directives refer to controllers. Would this start to become confusing in a large application with many directives and methods in controllers all servicing them? I saw examples of controllers inside of directives. Again this seems confusing to me. Why would I need to do that?  Thanks in advance for your advice on this.

Comment: @Gemma I use services for _application wide_ storage, like keeping track of user authentication. If a directive needed to access the current user info, doing so via the service makes sense. Interacting though with the current _page_ of your app, which is limited to a certain controller and scope, it keeps the app cleaner to have directives talk directly to the controller. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Calling outer scope functions like that is risky, because it makes assumptions about the surrounding scope. What would happen if the directive were used in a different context?

There are better[1] strategies that a reusable directive may employ to communicate with the outside world:

- Deferring its dependencies to services. This is more appropriate for system wide features. I guess it doesn't apply to your example.
- Defining an isolate scope that contains some `&attr` property which is bound to an expression from an outer scope. The directive can call that expression as a method of its private scope.

As an example of this second strategy, I've modified your example. See it in action here http://plnkr.co/5uOBNu

```
var app = angular.module('twitterApp', []);
app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.loadMoreTweets = function() {
        alert("Loading tweets!");
    };
});

app.directive("specialEnter", function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            onEnter: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("mouseenter", function() {
                scope.onEnter();
            });
        }
    };
});

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div special-enter on-enter="loadMoreTweets()">Hover here!</div>
</div>
```

[1] "Better" in a sense of avoiding hard-wired dependencies.

Comment: _ can you clarify what you mean. You disagree to .. ?  Can you show in a few lines how you feel it should be coded. Thanks.

Comment: I'm preparing an extending edit. But my disagreement is about liberally using outer scope functions and data, like the example you used.